# TextView crash?

Tags: android, crash, textview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


TextView tID;
TextView tName;
TextView tWorld;

protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.ps);


    tID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tID);
    tName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tName);
    tWorld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tWorld);
}

public void Search(View view) {

    int clist = -2;
    String oID = "";
    String oName = "";
    String oWorld = "";
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    while (clist != -1)
    {
        oID = tID.getText().toString();
        tID.setText(oID+"ddf"+"\n");
        oName = tName.getText().toString();
        clist = -1;
    }

}
}
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/VScroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tWorld"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" " />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I know this is probably really simple but looking online doesn't answer it...
why does this crash upon getting to here?:
I know this is probably really simple but looking online doesn't answer it...
why does this crash upon getting to here?:

```
while (clist != -1)
    {
        oID = tID.getText().toString();
        tID.setText(oID+"ddf"+"\n");
        oName = tName.getText().toString();
        clist = -1;
    }
```

**Edit***
Search() is an onClick button in ps.xml while the textview are in list.xml

Comment: Post the message displayed in your LogCat.

Comment: It might have something to do with resetting the content view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `onCreate()` method:

change from  `setContentView(R.layout.ps);`  to  `setContentView(R.layout.list);` because you are using `list.xml` as your main layout.

and delete this line `setContentView(R.layout.list);` inside your `Search()` method:

```
public void Search(View view) {

    int clist = -2;
    String oID = "";
    String oName = "";
    String oWorld = "";
   // Delete this line setContentView(R.layout.list);
    while (clist != -1)
    {
        oID = tID.getText().toString();
        tID.setText(oID+"ddf"+"\n");
        oName = tName.getText().toString();
        clist = -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: is there not another method, i need both of the xmls

Comment: I would of liked to of kept the list.xml but it works thanks to you and a bunch of setVisibility's